# During the deployment Heroku automatically adds postgress Database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have an application that I am trying to deploy to Heroku. I am facing an interesting situation, where a postgres database instance is getting created automatically without me provisioning one. In addition, env variable with DATABASE_URL is getting created automatically at the same time.

It is not a problem as for now, but later we would like to connect to existing DB. We are not able to modify config variable DATABASE_URL

Is there a way to disable automatic creation of Postgres DB

Comment: Try `heroku addons:destroy [name]`, where name is the name of the add on from `heroku addons`

Comment: If you include an [`app.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-up-apps-using-the-heroku-platform-api) with `"addons": []` (or including whatever non-Postgres addons you want) and then provision your app does Postgres get skipped?

Comment: I want to skip the automatic creation of Postgres and DATABASE_URL, because I am going to use an existing database which is outside of Heroku